# PHP regex pattern exclude if inside another pattern

Tags: php, regex

How using PHP regex could a match be excluded if the pattern is inside another pattern.

The string/template being using looks like this:

```
{employee.name}
{history}
    {employee.name}
{/history}
```

The PHP regex pattern being used is this:

```
{employee([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)}
```

The problem with this pattern is that it will match  `{employee.name}` twice. It needs to exclude the match if it's inside `{history}*{/history}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that I find useful is to use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left side, (**saying** *throw this away, it's garbage*) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side. You can then grab your matches from `$matches[1]` ...

```
preg_match_all('~{history}.*?{/history}|({employee[a-z0-9.]+})~si', $str, $matches);
print_r(array_filter($matches[1]));
```

Alternatively, you can use backtracking control verbs:

```
preg_match_all('~{history}.*?{/history}(*SKIP)(*F)|{employee[a-z0-9.]+}~si', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{employee([A-Za-z0-9\.]+)}(?!\s*{\/\w+})
```

`(?!\s*{\/\w+})` Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below